# Bug change limit from toolbar advance search collection

Tags: magento-1.9, product-collection, pagination, advanced-search

i face strange issue using advance search filter. When i select **multiselect** from advance search they

`{baseUrl}/catalogsearch/advanced/`

[image]

when apply search url bocome like this.

`{baseUrl}/catalogsearch/advanced/result/?an_material_class[]=2733`

they show desire result.

[image]

when i set **page limit**.

[image]

then url become like

`{baseUrl}/catalogsearch/advanced/?an_material_class%255B0%255D=27337` like this

[image]

i think there some bug in **url encoding**. if any one have face this issue let me. help will b appreciated
thanks in advance

Comment: is this a custom module which creates this URL for advance search on select filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is bug in default Magento it is not url encode issue it is javascript issue you can fixed is simply by changing.

**app/design/frontend/rwd/default/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml**

on line **85**

From

```
onchange="setLocation(this.value)"
```

To

```
 onchange="window.location.href =this.value"
```